# UITableView not loading properly because of external DataSource and Delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. Today, I moved it's `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to a separate file. It looks like this.

```
@interface TableDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end

@interface TableDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end



@implementation TableDelegate

@synthesize delegate;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"heightForHeaderInSection");
    return 20.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"header!");
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath");
    return 48.0f;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    [((UIViewController *)delegate).view endEditing:YES];
}

@end

@implementation RequestTableDataSource

@synthesize delegate;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 6;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I then construct my `UITableView` as below:

```
TableDelegate *tableDelegate = [[TableDelegate alloc] init];
tableDelegate.delegate = self;

TableDataSource *tableDataSource = [[TableDataSource alloc] init];
tableDataSource.delegate = self;

self.testTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.testTable.delegate = tableDelegate;
self.testTable.dataSource = tableDataSource;
[self.view addSubview:self.testTable];
```

Now, when I compile my app I get a blank `UITableView` without any content. I see some of the logs in the console, but not the logs for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `viewForHeaderInSection`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any object holding strong references to `TableDataSource` and `TableDelegate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` holds a `weak` reference to its delegate and datasource, so the ones you are creating have nothing holding a `strong` reference to them and are deallocated at the end of your method.

You should store them in a `strong` property on your view controller so they don't get deallocated until you are done using them.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewDelegate acts as a helper to interact with table View, So moving UITableViewDelegate is not a good idea for code reusability. But UITableViewDataSource helps on providing data for Table view. As per apple WWDC titled [Advanced User Interfaces With Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2014/)  (Session 232). It actually promotes data source reusability and clarifies the responsibility of your controller. you can keep datasource separate file. Please see [github repo KPPopOverTableView](https://github.com/kaushlendrapal/KPPopOverTableView) as a referance to implement it.